# itemselector - Gap size of the columns

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, itemselector

I want to resize gap between columns in `itemselector` but I couldn't find any reference. Actually buttons visible but looks weird so that I would resize the gap.

```
{
   xtype: 'itemselector',
   name: 'itemselector',
   id: 'itemselect-field',
   anchor: '100%',
   maxHeight: 370,
   baseBodyCls: 'puar-select',
   imagePath: '../assets/images',
   store: puar,
   <?php
       if ($this->session->userdata('person_puar')) {
          echo ("value:"."[".$this->session->userdata('person_puar')."],");
       } else {
          echo ("value:[],");
       }
   ?>
   displayField: 'EKSG_BEZ',
   valueField: 'EKSG',
   allowBlank: false,
   fromTitle: 'Mevcut',
   toTitle: 'Seçilen',
   buttons: ['add', 'remove'],
   buttonsText: {add: 'ekle', remove: 'çıkar'}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change this out of the box. It is all packed into a `hbox` layout with the `stretch` option where only the two multiselect boxes have a `flex` value applied. And this should work so I guess there is a render issue so that the layout got a wrong width from the container containing the buttons.

Which exact ExtJS version do you use and does this occur in all browsers (IE,FF,Chrome,Safari,Opera)?

One quick solution may be to add a width on your own but you have to extend for that. Here is the part where you would need to apply the tweak/ which you need to override:

```
setupItems: function() {
    var me = this;

    me.fromField = me.createList(me.fromTitle);
    me.toField = me.createList(me.toTitle);

    return [
        me.fromField,
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            margins: '0 4',
            // begin new
            width: 40, // you have to test for the optimal width
            // end new
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                pack: 'center'
            },
            items: me.createButtons()
        },
        me.toField
    ];
},
```

Comment: Dear sra, the ExtJS version is 4.2. Yes, I tried IE and Firefox, both same. I would try another way which is adding a css class to column but I didn't find any reference as well :(

Comment: @OğuzÇelikdemir Yes, this is because there is no such option. You can simply not apply any configuration to that container. You may test if the error is gone in 4.2.2 or you will need to do as I suggested and override the `setupItems` method